# How to optimize Python code to use Multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a Python code that rebins a numpy array for downsampling. However, when the input array is large this has to be done in a loop by windowing the data into smaller chunks.

What I am looking for right now is a way to use multiprocessing to speed-up the `rebin` function. Currently the function uses a single CPU. I have some knowledge of the multiprocessing module but I would appreciate advice on converting the below code to use multiprocessing.

> NOTE: I appreciate recommendations (probably more
> pythonic) that can speed-up the below function differently. However, I
> am also keen to learn if someone can help upgrade the below code to be
> suitable for multiprocessing.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def rebin(arr, new_shape):
    shape = (arr.shape[0], new_shape[0], arr.shape[1] // new_shape[0],
             new_shape[1], arr.shape[2] // new_shape[1])
    return arr.reshape(shape).mean(-1).mean(2)


def rebinner(arr, window):
    # w is the window size used to perform rebin on a fixed size window as the entire
    # data cannot be fit in memory for large data size.
    y = []
    for j in tqdm(range(0, arr.shape[0], window)):
        y.append(rebin(arr[j:j + window, :, None]*arr[j:j + window, None, :], [32, 32]))
    return np.concatenate(y, axis=0)


arr = np.random.random((1000,2560,))
```

The below code is run in a jupyter notebook cell for checking execution time. Can also be used in a script using timeit.

```
%%time
print(rebinner(arr, window=10).shape)
```

Expected Output:

```
(1000, 32, 32)
CPU times: user 8.52 s, sys: 4.58 s, total: 13.1 s
Wall time: 13.1 s
```

#### UPDATE 1:

**Output using numba library as suggested by @john-zwinck**

Based on the comments from @johnzwinck I updated the code slightly and included numa decorators. However, the new script throws assertion error and I am not quite sure what is causing that. Below is the updated code and corresponding error message.

```
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit(nopython=True)
def rebinner2(arr, new_shape):
    shape = (arr.shape[0], new_shape[0], arr.shape[1] // new_shape[0],
             new_shape[1], arr.shape[2] // new_shape[1])
    return arr.reshape(shape).mean(-1).mean(2)


@numba.njit(nopython=True)
def rebinner1(arr, window):
    return [rebinner2(np.random.random((window, 1, 2560))*np.random.random((window, 2560, 1)),
                      [32, 32]) for j in range(0, arr.shape[0], window)]
    # return [rebinner2(arr[j:j + window, :, None]*arr[j:j + window, None, :],
    # [32, 32]) for j in range(0, arr.shape[0], window)]


def rebinner(arr, window):
    return np.concatenate(rebinner1(arr,window), axis=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = np.random.random((1000, 2560))
    print(rebinner(arr, window=10).shape)
    # print(rebinner1(arr, window=10).shape)
```

Output:

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py:252: RuntimeWarning: nopython is set for njit and is ignored
  warnings.warn('nopython is set for njit and is ignored', RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_tester.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(rebinner(arr, window=10).shape)
  File "numba_tester.py", line 23, in rebinner
    return np.concatenate(rebinner1(arr,window), axis=0)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 358, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
AssertionError()
- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
AssertionError()

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.mean for array(float64, 5d, C))
During: typing of call at numba_tester.py (9)


File "numba_tester.py", line 9:
def rebinner2(arr, new_shape):
    <source elided>
             new_shape[1], arr.shape[2] // new_shape[1])
    return arr.reshape(shape).mean(-1).mean(2)
    ^

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function rebinner2 at 0x7f6c5743e730>))
During: typing of call at numba_tester.py (17)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function rebinner2 at 0x7f6c5743e730>))
During: typing of call at numba_tester.py (17)


File "numba_tester.py", line 17:
def rebinner1(arr, window):
    <source elided>
    return [rebinner2(np.random.random((window, 1, 2560))*np.random.random((window, 2560, 1)),
                      [32, 32]) for j in range(0, arr.shape[0], window)]
```

Notes: The above code works fine when implemented without the numba decorators. I have simplified `rebinner2` by using random arrays instead of the actual slice-transpose-multiply operation (to check if that caused issues for numba but it did not).

#### UPDATE 2:

Modified numba code to work but there is no performance gain.

As suggested by @JohnZwinck I changed `njit` to `jit`. This disables `nopython` mode. However, when checking time required for execution it seems the numba method now performs worse (probably because disabling nopython loses optimization).

With Numba:

```
(5000, 32, 32)
real:   1m11.538s
user:   0m49.137s
sys :   0m22.872s
```

Without Numba:

```
(5000, 32, 32)
real:   1m2.439s
user:   0m41.721s
sys :   0m21.152s
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the unnecessary `tqdm` (progress bar) and add Numba to speed it up like this (untested, but should be close to what you need):

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def rebinner2(arr, new_shape):
    shape = (arr.shape[0], new_shape[0], arr.shape[1] // new_shape[0],
             new_shape[1], arr.shape[2] // new_shape[1])
    return arr.reshape(shape).mean(-1).mean(2)

@numba.njit
def rebinner1(arr, window):
    return [rebinner2(arr[j:j + w, :, None]*arr[j:j + w, None, :], [32, 32]) for j in range(0, arr.shape[0], window)]

def rebinner(arr, window):
    return np.concatenate(rebinner1, axis=0)
```

I wrapped `np.concatenate()` in a non-Numba function because I'm not sure if Numba supports the `axis` argument.

Using multiple cores for this is probably pointless unless your data are truly gigantic, in which case you should simply load a subset of the data in each process.  But Numba will make the loop far faster than multiple cores.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using numba. However, it is throwing errors that I am not able to debug. Please refer to update 1 above for the details. I will continue to debug but let me know if you are aware on what's causing the error.

Comment: @DrSpill: The first step is to try plain `@numba.jit` without nopython mode.  That mode is more flexible, if you still have errors in that mode please post them.

Comment: adding nopython argument was just a test I was doing to see if that helps. The output is exactly the same with or without that argument. Also to ensure numba works in my system otherwise, I tried a sample code from their doc which works just fine. I think the error arises from reshape or mean functions in rebinner2.

Comment: Did you try `jit` instead of `njit` (without mentioning `nopython`)?  Because `njit` is like `jit(nopython=True)`...and I want you to try with `nopython=False` which means `jit` with no arguments.

Comment: I tried using jit. The code works. But there is no performance gain. On the contrary it appears to be slightly slower than non-numba method. Added time results in Update 2

Comment: All right. Have you tried resolving the error messages you got? Google them for example.

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve the issue so far. I am just saving the outcomes after data generation from each run so I can reuse it without generating again. I am still in search for ways to optimize the operation.